# What calculus theory I should study to understand back-propagation in general form?

Tags: linear-algebra, neural-networks

I understand mnemonic of chain rule. But for example if I have some error function *E* and *I* want to find its first derivative against some matrix *W*. Or if I have some vector valued function *V* and I also want to find its derivative of some matrix *W* what kind of entities these would be?

$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial W} = ?$$ $$\frac{\partial V}{\partial W} = ?$$

These are tensors? Or multi dimensional arrays? What operation is between entities in some derivate chain, is a matrix multiplication, or dot product? What should I study to understand these entities tensor algebra, differential geometry?

I know that there are plenty materials in web that avoid this question completely, or introduce silly notation like using $$\partial w_{ij}$$ instead of $$\partial W$$ but I tired follow that I want to see the general form. I want to operate and see entities as they are

Comment: Why is notation  the $\partial w_{ij}$silly? It is the standard  notation and tells you what is going on.  On the other hand $\partial W$ is simply a short notation for the sum of the derivatives after all components of $W$.  You don't need anything fancy to understand these operations. Just write your error function in dependence of all matrix elements and use the stadnad chain rule.

Comment: @klirk See this example http://www.wildml.com/2015/10/recurrent-neural-networks-tutorial-part-3-backpropagation-through-time-and-vanishing-gradients/ . Author pretends for simplicity, he didn't  use dwij notation but instead use dW. But if things are so simple why did he use "outer products". Outer products are applicable for vectors not scalars? So I guess you are wrong and things are not so simple

Comment: It is a while, since I dealt with neural networks, but in my memory there was nothing mathematically complicated going on in backpropagation. Look at the article linked in yours: http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html  You probably mean expressions like in BP1a, sometimes called Hadamard product.

Comment: Just think about this entity $$\frac{\partial (Wx)}{\partial W}$$. It is not hard to see that this entity is already not a matrix by itself. Entities such that are pretty common to appear in backprop derivation

Comment: See [matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus).

Comment: You don't need matrix calculus for backpropagation, only the chain rule and the total derivative to compute the gradient of the gradient descent. But writing the obtained equations in matrix form can help to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the relevant parts of Tom Mitchells book

> T. M. Mitchell, Machine learning, ser. McGraw Hill series in computer science.
>   McGraw-Hill, 1997.

I made a short summary in my own words in [my bachelors thesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.09030.pdf#page=32)

Things to understand for gradient descent in neural networks:

### The Gradient

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a function:

$$f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) = (F_1(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n), F_2(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n), \dots, F_m(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n))$$

Then the gradient of $f$ is denoted by $\nabla f$ and
$$\nabla f = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_1}, 
 & \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_2}& \dots  &\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_n}\\
\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x_1}, 
 & \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x_2}& \dots  &\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x_n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial F_m}{\partial x_1}, 
 & \frac{\partial F_m}{\partial x_2}& \dots  &\frac{\partial F_m}{\partial x_n}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

You can see that you can decompose the problem by output neuron ($F_i$)

- TODO: Example (e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1815055/6876 )
- TODO: Explain $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}$ notation
- http://www.markusengelhardt.com/skripte/grad-div-rot.pdf (German)

### The chain rule

(To be continued - I need to go to work now)

Comment: And the total derivative : if $g(t) = f(x(t),y(t))$ then $$g'(t) = x'(t) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x(t),y(t))+y'(t) \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x(t),y(t))$$